# How to disable all SLF4J messages

Tags: java, slf4j

I am writing a simple five class command line application. I am using a serial port library `jssc` which has SLF4J implemented. Because of this I get the following text to the console:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I have read the various questions and answers and have downloaded the `slf4j-nop-1.7.9.jar` which is in the class path for the project.

I do not want nor need logging for this application. It runs from the command line, does its 10 seconds worth of work, and ends. No logging required at all. How do I get rid of even the most basic of SLF4J messages?

BTW, I can see `org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.class` in the `slf4j-nop-1.7.9.jar` in the class path, yet it fails to load. Why?

And finally, why is this so complex? I just want it to shut up!

Comment: Can't you just redirect the output?

Comment: I need the output for showing runtime messages

Comment: You wrote that you don't want or need logging..

Comment: There is a difference between logging and showing runtime console messages

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the problem. You do need the `slf4j-nop-1.7.9.jar`. You also need to add the noop jar to the project Run Configuration/ Dependencies tab

Sigh...